# Firebase Authentication Requires Two 'Login' Calls

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to hard code an authentication layer for my web app, so I can see whether a user is an 'admin' or not. The login works if I do not put the 'if statement'  before the sign in function. But when I add it, it requires me to press the login button twice before it works.

**Login Function:**

```
function login() {
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;
  var login = [];
  var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("Parking Lots");
  usersRef.orderByChild("admin").on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      login.push(childData.admin);
    });
  });
  firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
    .then(function () {
      if(login.includes(userEmail)){
       return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass);
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      window.alert("Fail");
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}
```

**HTML Login Button:**

I did some research and for others it worked when you set the button type="button", but it does not work for me.

```
<div id="login_div" class="main-div">
    <h3>Firebase Web login Example</h3>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" />
    <button type="button" onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
  </div>
```

*Edit:*
**New Working Login Function:**

```
function login() {
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;
  var login = [];

  var usersRef = firebase.database().ref("Parking Lots");
  return usersRef.orderByChild("admin").once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      login.push(childData.admin);
    });
    if(login.includes(userEmail)){
      firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
      .then(function () {
        return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        window.alert("Password incorrect");
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
      });
    }
    else {
      window.alert("Please enter another email");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`on()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before anything happens with the database.   It's entirely possible that the first response from the callback you pass to `on()` could trigger after the call to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.  You should probably be using `once()` instead, and use the promise it returns before trying to process the results of its query.  Also, you should be using `once()` because I strongly suspect you don't want that listener to keep getting invoked every time the data at the given location changes.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code to the working one for future reference

Comment: Actually you should leave the original code there, and update with the correct code, so people who might have a similar problem can see what the fix is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to add the `type` button property for button submitting the login form.. after setting it to `type="button"` everything works as expected.. spent 3 hours of solving this issue