# Facebook and Google requires two login click to login with Firebase Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have React web application with firebase auth (mail, Facebook, Google).

Google and Facebook work only after 2 login clicks.

The code is equal, just the provider is different.

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import { app } from "../../../../config/firebase";

const signupWithGoogle = (user, userInfo)=>{
    app.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      firstName: userInfo.profile.given_name,
      lastName: userInfo.profile.family_name});
      const batch = app.firestore().batch();
      const initData = [
        { Applied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Applied' } },
        { Contract: { positionIds: [], title: 'Contract' } },
        { Denied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Denied' } },
        { InProgress: { positionIds: [], title: 'In Progress' } },
        { ReceivedTask: { positionIds: [], title: 'Received Task' } },
      ];
      initData.forEach((doc) => {
        const docRef = app
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .doc( user.uid)
          .collection('columns')
          .doc(Object.keys(doc)[0]);
        batch.set(docRef, Object.values(doc)[0]);
      });
     const batchCommit= batch.commit();
      return batchCommit;
}

export const googleLogin = async (
  history
) => {
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    await  firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then( resp => {
      let {user, credential,additionalUserInfo: userInfo} = resp;
      if (userInfo.isNewUser) signupWithGoogle(user, userInfo);
    }).then(()=>
    history.push('/')
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
};
```

I saw this question, but didn't help.([Firebase Authentication Requires Two 'Login' Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271523/firebase-authentication-requires-two-login-calls))

Comment: Please include the code where this sign in method is called and how you are handling navigation on the root pages (i.e. How you go from `/` to the login screen)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Firebase Authentication with Facebook, I had to register two times to make it works.
The problem was in my HTLM, I used a form.
I changed for a simpler code, and it worked.

Comment: Can you share what changes made it work ?

Answer (score -1):

While waiting for where you call your function from, as your issue would relate to improper state management, here are some edits you can make to the code you have shared so far to squash some problems that it has.

---

In your `signupWithGoogle` function, you create a floating promise that should be included in the write batch that you use to create the `/users/{userId}/columns` collection. Because you use `Object.keys(doc)[0]` and `Object.values(doc)[0]`, you should consider using an array of `[docId, docData]` pairs or a JSON-like object structure like so:

```
// prepare data to add to the user's columns collection
const initColumnsData = {
  Applied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Applied' },
  Contract: { positionIds: [], title: 'Contract' },
  Denied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Denied' },
  InProgress: { positionIds: [], title: 'In Progress' },
  ReceivedTask: { positionIds: [], title: 'Received Task' }
};

// queue columns data upload
Object.entries(initColumnsData)
  .forEach(([docId, docData]) => {
    const docRef = userDocRef
      .collection('columns')
      .doc(docId);
    batch.set(docRef, docData);
  });
```

As you mentioned that a lot of your code is shared aside from the provider implementation, you should consider extracting the common code from those functions:

```
const initUserData = (user, userDocData) => {
  // init write batch
  const batch = app.firestore().batch();
  
  // init ref to user data
  const userDocRef = app.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid);
  
  // queue user data upload
  batch.set(userDocRef, userDocData);
  
  // prepare data to add to the user's columns collection
  const initColumnsData = {
    Applied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Applied' },
    Contract: { positionIds: [], title: 'Contract' },
    Denied: { positionIds: [], title: 'Denied' },
    InProgress: { positionIds: [], title: 'In Progress' },
    ReceivedTask: { positionIds: [], title: 'Received Task' }
  };

  // queue columns data upload
  Object.entries(initColumnsData)
    .forEach(([docId, docData]) => {
      const docRef = userDocRef
        .collection('columns')
        .doc(docId);
      batch.set(docRef, docData);
    });
  
  // make the changes
  return batch.commit();
}

const initUserDataForGoogle(user, userInfo) {
  return initUserData(user, {
    firstName: userInfo.profile.given_name,
    lastName: userInfo.profile.family_name
  });
}

const initUserDataForFacebook(user, userInfo) {
  return initUserData(user, {
    firstName: /* ... */,
    lastName: /* ... */
  });
}
```

When exporting a function to be called elsewhere, avoid causing "side effects" (like navigating using the History API) and don't trap errors (using `.catch()` without rethrowing the error). The calling code should handle the result and any errors itself.

```
export const loginWithGoogle = async () => {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  return firebase.auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(async resp => {
      const {user, credential, additionalUserInfo: userInfo} = resp;
      
      if (userInfo.isNewUser)
        await initUserDataForGoogle(user, userInfo);

      return user;
    });
};
```

Then in your components, you'd use:

```
setLoading(true);
/* await/return */ loginWithGoogle()
  .then(() => {
    history.push('/');
    // or
    // setLoading(false)
    // then do something
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("loginWithGoogle failed: ", err);
    setLoading(false);
    setError("Failed to log in with Google!"); // <- displayed in UI to user
  });
```

Comment: can you provide a minified answer? something that is on topic to the question.

Comment: @DIGIByte I wrote this while waiting on OP to edit their question with where the code is called but they haven't yet done it. Rather than just delete what I had so far, I just posted it.

Comment: StackOverflow is more focused on answering questions rather than code review.
that's why this site exists: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/